# Adding title in TileMill/Mapbox map?

Tags: mapbox, tilemill

I have successfully made a legend and teasers for a tilemill map. However, I don't know how to add a title and don't see a function for it.

If I wanted to add a title, how would I do that?

Comment: You can modify the HTML/CSS to your requirements for Title https://www.mapbox.com/tilemill/docs/guides/advanced-legends/

Comment: The above documentation does not describe adding an extra legend window, which is essentially what the asker is seeking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The normal workflow shown in most TileMill maps is to have a title incorporated into the legend box.

When you create your Mapbox webmap with your TileMill tiles, a title box will be generated with the title you name your Mapbox map with.

Comment: When will the title box be generated? I'm not seeing it.

Comment: Give your Mapbox webmap a title, a description if you'd like, and save it. Copy the "share map url," and paste the URL in a new browser window to view the map as someone would be viewing it whom you shared it with. There will be a title block in the top left with the map name and description.